# Is it acceptable to post someone else comment as an answer to increase the percentage of answered questions?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

So now and then, I check the unanswered tab to see whether there are unanswered questions. A couple of them contain comments that include an answer.

For some of the Q&As I have asked the person that placed the comment whether they could post it as an answer.

Unfortunately, in the majority of the cases the answer remains unanswered as some users do not post answers.

Now I wonder whether it is acceptable if I extend a comment that is actually an answer, write it in my own words and post it as an answer.

On one hand it feels bad to post someones comment as an answer, but on the other hand it is also tedious that the number of unanswered questions is increasing while there are comments that basically answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you're able to understand the answer expressed in some other venue (whether comments on the question, another forum, the official documentation...) then writing up an answer that makes it available to future readers is an admirable thing to do.

[Give credit where credit is due](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), of course.

#### See also: [What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins)

Comment: And then flag that comment for deletion!